# where is that tool where I can load IE6 and IE7 on the same computer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

where is that tool where I can load IE6 and IE7 on the same computer?

testing for cross-browser issues.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and something that can easily be determined by a google search.

Comment: Even simple questions are allowed, and in fact. And I think the goal of this site is to be the answer from the google search! ;)

Comment: @Darien Ford: I'd definitely disagree - testing code (even HTML/CSS) is as much a part of programming as writing the code itself.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thats what the voting is all about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download one of the [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef). These will work with [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (also a free download). The images available (at this time) are:

- Windows XP SP3 with IE6
- Windows XP SP3 with IE7
- Windows XP SP3 with IE8
- Windows Vista with IE7
- Windows Vista with IE8

Note that these are time bombed and if you choose to use this solution you will need to download versions with the expiry date extended at some point. Presumably one day Microsoft will cease to offer the images for the older OSs as well.

Comment: +1. I've been using these for more than two years now, each time they expire Microsoft refreshes them. Also of note, the previous batch (which expired sometime in April) seemed to continue working after the expiry date, although they shut down after an hour of use.

Answer (score 3):

If you want reliable cross-browser testing, forget about loading ie6 and 7 (and 8?) on the same machine. I can't recommend it. It's never worked for me.

Try ie tester http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage, I've only had positive experiences with it, and everyone I show it to, loves it.

Comment: +1 For the link. Unfortunately I personally have found IETester to be a bit buggy. Better than nothing, though.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean MultipleIEs?

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Answer (score 1):

it is this tool

http://blogs.msdn.com/xweb/archive/2009/03/18/Microsoft-Expression-Web-SuperPreview-for-Windows-Internet-Explorer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have always used:
http://browsershots.org/

It allows you to view the site in multiple browsers for multiple OS's

Answer (score 0):

Better use VMWare or another Virtual Machine solution. That way, you won't just test with different browsers but you'd also be able to test with many different environments! (E.g. Windows 2000 with IE7, Windows XP with IE5, Windows 7 with IE8, Linux with FireFox, Vista with Chrome...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also download IE6eolas_nt.zip  from http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/win32/standalone

It does have a couple of issues though:

1. Transparency hacks for IE6 do not work.
2. conditional comments think that the browser is IE7 (or whatever browser you actually have installed).

FYI, http://browsers.evolt.org is a repository of (very likely) every browser, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with using VMs. I used to use Multiple IEs, but then discovered that conditional comments don't work if you have more than one version installed. Not much use if you have to use that ugly hack, which I'm afraid I do. browsershots looks quite cool, but not fast enough for me!
If only we were rid of the foulness of IE!